# jquery loop table while adding up values

Tags: jquery

I have the following table which gets populated by php and contains values in the "Calories", "Protein", "Carbs", and "Fats" columns. I am trying to write a jquery script which will iterate through the table and total all the calorie values, protein values, carbs values, and fats values. I am very new to jquery, so I'm having a bit of a rough time. Here's the structure:

```
<table id="planner_table" class="display">
          <thead class="planner_table_head">
            <tr>
              <th class="planner_th">Meal Name</td>

              <th class="planner_th">Calories</th>

              <th class="planner_th">Protein</th>

              <th class="planner_th">Carbs</th>

              <th class="planner_th">Fats</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <?php $dao->fillPlanner($_SESSION['user_id']); ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

these are what the entries look like which are generated by the PHP:

```
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="centered">' . content . '</td>';
echo '<td class="centered cals">' . content . '</td>';
echo '<td class="centered prot">' . content . '</td>';
echo '<td class="centered carbs">' . content . '</td>';
echo '<td class="centered fats">' . content . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show what the rendered HTML of the `table` element is? Because that's what jQuery/JavaScript is working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To total the number of calories in the calories column, do this:

```
var totalCals = 0;

$('td.cals').each(function(){
    totalCals += parseInt($(this).html(), 10);
});
```

This assumes the only content within each  is just the number to be added.

You can do the same for the other column types as well.

Comment: I was doing this, but I was saying ('td .cals') which kept returning an empty array... I didn't know that white space made a difference... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.each()` function to iterate through dom elements, and here it's the `<tr>`.
So basically, here is a way to do it (I didn't write it totally so you will finish it by yourself) :

```
$('#planner_table tr').each(function(i) {
    var cals = $('td.cals', this);
    var prot = $('td.prot', this);
    var carbs = $('td.carbs', this);
    var fats = $('td.fats', this);
});
```